# How to set the text from the for loop?

Tags: objective-c

I have an array:

```
@[2:00 am, 3:00 am, 4:00 pm, 5:00 pm, 6:00 pm];
```

Suppose the current time is 4:00 pm and I want the text `5:00 pm` to be printed in a UILabel as it is greater than `4:00 pm`.

So I used the for loop below:

```
for (int i=0;  i < prayerTimesArray.count ; i++) {

    NSTimeInterval arrayTime = [[prayerTimesArray objectAtIndex:i] timeIntervalSince1970];
    NSLog(@"The Fajr Time In Miliseconds is %f",arrayTime);

    if(currentTime < arrayTime)
    {
        _ramadhanTimeLabel.text=[prayerTitleArray objectAtIndex:i];
        [self setCustomProgressViewinBootom];
        progressViewBootom.progress=currentTime/arrayTime;
    }
}
```

But it prints `6:00 pm` to the label as it again loops but I need `5:00 pm` to be printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to exit from the loop using `break` once you set `5:00 pm` to the label's text:

Here is slightly improved *(more readable)* version of your loop:

```
for (NSDate *date in prayerTimesArray) {
  NSTimeInterval arrayTime = [date timeIntervalSince1970];
  NSLog(@"The Fajr Time In Miliseconds is %f", arrayTime);

  if(currentTime < arrayTime) {
    _ramadhanTimeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", arrayTime];
    [self setCustomProgressViewinBootom];
    progressViewBootom.progress = currentTime / arrayTime;
    break;
  }
}
```